# Divs side by side and under each other

Tags: javascript

First post here. I will provide pictures of the problem.

Hello!

I am currently working with a project where i have 2 divs that should always be on the top of the page. Side by side. That's no problem. The problem appears when i add new divs which should be side by side, but under the first 2 ones.

The size of the first 2 divs differ, and if the second of the 2 top ones is "shorter" than the first one, the ones that i add under these two ends up at wierd positions.

Every block is in ones own div and every div is in a big div. Hope you guys can help.

Here is the  classes:

```
    .panelLeft {
         width: 40%;
         float: left;
     }        

    .panel {
        background: #eee;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 10px;
        border-radius: 7px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 49px -23px rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 49px -23px rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
        box-shadow: 0px 9px 49px -23px rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
    }

    .displayNone {
        display: none;
    }
```

Here is some example code:

```
<div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>        
                    <td><asp:Linkbutton runat="server" ID="linkbutton1" Text="Toggle div1" OnClientClick="toggleDiv('divNr1'); return false;" />:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>        
                    <td><asp:Linkbutton runat="server" ID="linkbutton2" Text="Toggle div2" OnClientClick="toggleDiv('divNr2'); return false;" />:</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>


        <div id="divNr1" class="panelLeft panel displayNone" runat="server">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="someLiteral1" Text="Some text"/></td>
                </tr>  
            </table>
        </div>

        <div id="divNr2" class="panelLeft panel displayNone" runat="server">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="someLiteral2" Text="Some text"/></td>
                </tr>   
            </table>
        </div>
     </div>
```

And here is the toggle funtcion:

```
function toggleDiv(divName) {
    if (divName  === 'divNr1') {
            divNr1.toggle("fast");
        }
        else if (divName  === 'divNr2') {
            divNr2.toggle("fast");
        } 
    }
```

Ill show you what i mean with a picture:

[image]

And how i want it is like this:

[image]

Thanks you so much!

Comment: Can you show us what have you done at this point? Any code sample would be great. Please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to SO please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site - Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE].

Comment: I have now idited my question with more information. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose each row of divs in another div. Like this:

```
<div>
  <div>left</div>
  <div>right</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>left</div>
  <div>right</div>
</div>
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use inline-block for your divs, like this;

```
<div id="div1"> Div 1</div>
<div id="div2"> Div 2</div>
<div id="div3"> Div 3</div>
<div id="div4"> Div 4</div>
<div id="div5"> Div 5</div>
```

and this CSS

```
body {
  font-size: 0;
}
div {
  width:45%;
  margin: 1px 2.5%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#div1 {height: 150px;}
```

`font-size: 0` is to make your dimensions work correctly but don't forget to put the font-sizes back in again.

https://codepen.io/chrispink/pen/EvxEoe

Comment: I'm gonna try this out tomorrow. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hello sir. It kind of works, the problem appears when i use the .toggle function. i am toggling the visibility of the divs by pressing the "Show div" button. Then it sets the display to block, instead of inline-block.

Comment: use `toggleClass('visible');` and define `.visible{ display: inline-block;}`

Comment: That didn't work at all... damn i can't get this to work :-/